# PHP: Select a random numbers, evenly spaced

Tags: php, random

What is the most effective way to create a PHP function that will pick a given amount of random number, but evenly spaced out and contain no duplicates?

For example say you wanted 3 random number between 0-6 the result could be **[0, 2, 5]** or **[1, 3, 6]**.

Any ideas on how to get started?

Comment: "How are 1 3 and 6 "evenly spaced out"? The gap betwen 3 and 6 is 50% larger than the gap between 1 and 3. Why not "1 3 5"?

Comment: If you got a set of rules about the possibilities, calculate them and choose one random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note that none of codes below will work directly as a copy paste.**

---

If you want to select **a** random number, use [`mt_rand(min, max)`](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php).

If you want to select a random number which is divisible by N, use `mt_rand(min, max)*N`.

If you want to select M random numbers which are all divisible by N, use a loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= M-1; $i++) {
    $result[$i] = mt_rand(min, max)*N;
}
print_r($result);
```

That is what I understand from your question.

Comment: I take from the question _M random numbers, all divisible by N_. I'd just like to add: The fact that the numbers are "random" means there is no **guarantee** that any two generated numbers will be evenly spaced. `mt_rand(0,6)` is just as likely to produce [0,1,5] or [2,5,6] as it is to produce [0,2,5] or [1,3,6].

Comment: It is mathematically **impossible** for **random** numbers to be ***evenly*** spaced. It's impossible by definition.

Comment: That's what I was going for, but you said it better :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you mean evenly spaced as in "all evens" then you could check the number against a modulus of 2: if ($n % 2 ==0) {//do thing with even numbers...}

array_rand(array(1,2,3,4,5,6...), 3); would give you 3 random numbers out of a pool of numbers, but they'd of course be random... not evenly spaced... evenly spaced numbers in a group would hardly be random by definition would it?

my opinion is to pick the index of the array at random, then add the element at that index by some interval, do that over however many iterations you need.

```
$random_numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$random_val = array_rand($random_numbers, 1);
$iterations = 3;
for ($i=0; $i<$iterations; $i++){
    $random_val = $random_val+2;
    print $random_val;
}
```